# How to validate a file format

Tags: shell

I wrote this shell script.  I got an error message for line 14 and 18, but I do not see what is  wrong. The script is supposed to analyze each file of `*.fq`.  If the first three characters of a given file do not match "HWI" then the script will just reply "invalide format", but if they match then the script will give me the number of "HWI" lines in that file.

```
!/bin/sh
for f in *.fq
do
a="$(head -n1 $f)"
c="$(expr substr $a 2 3)"
echo $c
nr="$(grep -w "HWI" $f | wc -l)
if [ "$c"="HWI" ] ;
then
  echo $f |  "the number of read of $f is $nr"
else
  echo"Invalide Format"
fi
done
```

Can anyone explain what my errors are?

Comment: `echo"foo"` is an error because you need a space between the command and the string. `echo $var | "string"` is an error unless the `string` is a command (and doesn't do anything useful unless that command reads data from standard input). Add the space and drop `$f |` from that other `echo` line. Oh, also **tell us the errors you get** so we don't have to guess.

Comment: In addition, fix the she-bang (`#!/bin/sh`), and your script doesn't have 18 lines, so this is probably just an excerpt, but if so, then quoting line numbers is fairly useless...

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax issues in your script, you can use a tool like http://www.shellcheck.net/ to detect some mistakes.
After indenting your code, here is a more correct (not perfect) version of what you wrote:

```
for f in *.fq 
do 
    a=$(head -n1 "$f")
    c=$(expr substr "$a" 2 3)
    echo "$c"
    nr=$(grep -w "HWI" "$f" | wc -l)
    if [ "$c" == "HWI" ]; then
        echo "The number of read of $f is $nr"
    else 
        echo "Invalide Format"
    fi
done
```

- No need for quotes " " around $(..)
- No need to pipe $f to echo (not sure what you were trying to do)
- Put quotes " " wrapping the variables to avoid word splitting

I did not run the code since I don't really know what you want to do, but at least the syntax should be better.

Answer (score 0):

Your code refined:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *.fq
do
a="$(head -n1 $f)"
c=$(expr "substr $a 2 3")
echo $c
nr="$(grep -w "HWI" $f | wc -l)"
if [ "$c"="HWI" ] ;
then
  echo $f  "the number of read of $f is $nr"
else
  echo "Invalide Format"
fi
done
```

> Errors:
>
> line 1: missing #
>
> line 5: wrong syntax in using `expr`
>
> line 7: missing quotation
>
> line 10: wrong syntax using `echo`
>
> line 12: missing space after `echo`
>
> last line: missing for loop closing `done`

Answer (score 0):

This test `[ "$c"="HWI" ]` will **always** be **true**.

The `[` command does different things depending on how many arguments it receives. When given 1 argument (discounting the mandatory `]` last argument), it returns success if the length of the argument is non-zero.

You are passing a single argument to the `[` command: `"$c"="HWI"` -- this string will have a length of at least **four**, so clearly non-zero.

For string comparison, you want spaces around the operator: `[ "$c" = "HWI" ]`

See this for all the gory details of how the `[` command is parsed: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128

---

My rewrite:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.fq; do
    read -N3 first3 < "$f"
    if [[ $first3 == "HWI" ]]; then
        echo "number of reads: $f: $(grep -Fwc HWI "$f")"
    else
        echo "Invalide Format: $f"
    fi
done
```